# How to export these results in a comma delimited csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to determine if there is a way to switch up what I have below and export it in a comma delimited csv file.

The script works fine and returns the data I care about, just not in a usable format.

The script gets users in a specific group and loops through the user list pulling additional information for each user. I'm not familiar with powershell so it's possible I'm making this harder than necessary based on lack of knowledge.

```
Import-module activedirectory

Function Process-Members($MemberList)
{
    foreach ($member in $MemberList)
    {
        Get-ADUser -Identity $member.samaccountname -Properties * | select Name, SamAccountName, Enabled, @{Name='LastLogon';Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}
        dsquery user -samid $member.samaccountname | dsget user -memberof | dsget group -samid
    }
}

$members = Get-ADGroupMember "MyGroupName" -recursive | Select-Object name, SamAccountName

Process-Members $members
```

Comment: why are you using `dsquery/dsget`? i think those results can be obtained via the AD cmdlets ... and if they can, then you will have far fewer problems making a CSV export ... [*grin*]

Comment: using dsquery/dsget because I don't know better. I'll research AD cmdlets, thanks for the info.

Comment: the AD* cmdlets will return a _basic_ set of properties. this is done to reduce the load on the server. you can get the entire set with `-Properties *` and see what all is available. try NOT to use that "give me all of them" thing in production since it WILL put a hefty load on your AD servers. ///// take a look at this >>> Active Directory: Get-ADUser Default and Extended Properties - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki — https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed your function because it is not entirely necessary for this process. You can easily modify it to use your function again. I also removed the dsquery and dsget commands because the ActiveDirectory module have commands that can get this information.

```
$members = Get-ADGroupMember "MyGroupName" -recursive | Select-Object name, SamAccountName

$Output = foreach ($member in $members) {

    Get-ADUser -Identity $member.SamAccountName -Properties * |
       select Name, SamAccountName, Enabled,
       @{Name='LastLogon';Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}},
       @{n='MemberOf';e={($_.MemberOf |% {Get-ADGroup $_}).SamAccountName -join "; "}}
}

$Output | Export-Csv -Path output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The `MemberOf` selected property is calculated by returning the `SamAccountName` property from a `Get-ADGroup` output and joining the results together with `;`. You can change that join character. By default leaving off the join, will join groups with a space, so if groups contain spaces, it could become confusing. The `%` is just an alias for `ForEach-Object`.
`Export-Csv` is used to create the comma-delimited CSV output file (output.csv).

For all versions of PowerShell (2.0 and above), you can use the following:

```
$members = Get-ADGroupMember "MyGroupName" -recursive | Select-Object name, SamAccountName

$Output = foreach ($member in $members) {

    Get-ADUser -Identity $member.SamAccountName -Properties * |
       select Name, SamAccountName, Enabled,
       @{Name='LastLogon';Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}},
       @{n='MemberOf';e={($_.MemberOf |% {Get-ADGroup $_ | Select -Expand SamAccountName}) -join "; "}}
}

$Output | Export-Csv -Path output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This does not give me the groups like my script did, but I can make this work, learned a lot from the way you put this together, thank you!

Comment: Would the fact that i'm using Powershell 2.0 be the reason I'm not seeing the groups in this example? I'm not in a position to upgrade this server at the moment to a more recent version.

Comment: That could definitely be a reason. I can try to test this on v2.0 and see what happens.

Comment: @user1904898 I added a 2.0 version at the bottom of the post, can you test that and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Thanks, the version you just added does work in 2.0. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell makes this super easy.

Your $members is a PSCollection, so you can literally just pass Process-Members into Export-Csv using a Pipe Operator.

```
Process-Members $members | Export-Csv -Path {Your Desired CSV Location}
```

That should do the trick.

Check out the man page here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6

As far as improving that script; in my opinion, you should do what would make the most sense for you to read at first glance. Powershell offers all kinds of tools to do fancy tricks. You could probably do this with a nifty one-liner, but if you look at the code and start drooling because it's impossible to tell what the one liner does, that's not great.

Personally, I don't like declaring functions in powershell unless I intend to re-use their functionality. I would just process your members into a variable which you can then pipe to export-csv, rather than creating a function. But it has no impact on performance, so that's just personal preference.

Comment: Exporting to CSV as is will be problematic. The dsquery results in a string array where the only property is Length. So that part of the output will show up as integer values in a column called Length.

Comment: example of the output when I try this.
Not sure how to edit the format below. It lists a row of user data, then where the users groups would be I just see empty line with three commas


#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser
"Name","SamAccountName","Enabled","LastLogon"
"last name first name","user name 1","True","5/6/2000 8:54:45 AM"
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
"last name first name","user name 2","True","5/6/2000 8:54:45 AM"
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
,,,
"last name first name","user name 3","True","5/6/2000 8:54:45 AM"

Comment: Check out AdminOfThings answer, it's better than mine. I didn't even notice you were using dsquery (which you don't have to!)